# How to fix 424 Runtime error on .AddItem for Listbox in VBA in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

This is probably a very stupid question but I've googled a lot and I can't find the solution. I'm new in VBA and I'm doing a very simple macro in MS Project. This is working fine until I'm trying to let the user choose from a list of reports. The object ListBox is not letting me add items using .AddItem method, I guess this is because a very simple thing I'm missing.

The following code is throwing a 424 runtime error on the line where I have the .AddItem:

```
Sub Macro2()
   Dim oReport As Report

   With myListBox
       For Each oReport In ActiveProject.Reports
           .AddItem oReport.Name
       Next oReport
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is MyListBox what you think it is? Does oReport have a value. Use F8 to step through your code, and the Immediate window to find the answer to these questions (using "? oReport.Name" will tell it to print the current report name for example)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, even including just a plain text, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Same thing, it makes no difference

Comment: @user1376672 Where is this code? In a userform module or a standard module?

Comment: In the standard module, in the body of the macro

Comment: Ah - I assumed that myListBox was a userform control, where is it - on a report? (I'm not familiar with MS Project)

Comment: It's a regular macro, I can even try adding items in a simple string with no loop and it doesn't make any difference :( I'm completly lost

Comment: but your `myListBox` object, presumable a ListBox control, where does it *live*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190621/discussion-between-callumda-and-user1376672).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code sample you gave Im pretty sure the problem is that this is a regular Sub and NOT code running INSIDE the form itself so it lacks the context, hence the error.
What you want to do is right click on the form in the explorer and hit 'View Code' and then insert this code below. It will load your control with the info you want. Any other controls on the form that need data should be loaded in a similar way.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
LoadList
End Sub

Sub LoadList()
  Dim oReport As Report
  With Me.MyListBox
       For Each oReport In ActiveProject.Reports
           .AddItem oReport.Name
       Next oReport
   End With
End Sub
```